# How to get equal spacing of navigation bar items if possible

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to have my 5 bar button items be equally spaced from each other.  What I essentially want is the equivalent of a stack view in my nav bar, with 5 buttons, and that stack view would have a height constraint as well as margin left = 25 margin right = 5, to provide room for the back button to come in.

Comment: Why can't you use the Objective-C code as a reference? It's all the same APIs.

Comment: I could.  But if somebody could provide a timeless reference on how to do it in Xcode that would be even better :)